# How to make each line of my data exported by sqlcmd presented in one line in the csv file

Tags: sql-server, csv, sqlcmd

I'm using SQLCMD to exporting data from SSMS and the I got about 50 million lines in total. All the data is exported to an csv file. However, I found that all the data as and the headers are all seperated into 2 lines in the csv file. For example, instead of having

```
id  name  age  sex
--- ----  ---  ---
1   Andy   20   M
2   Sally  25   F
```

I'am having this:

```
id  name  age
sex
--- ---- ---
---
1   Andy  20
M
2   Sally 25
F
```

I will need to import these data into another database so this file is obviously not working for me.

My data contains 17 columns and the command that I used is:

```
sqlcmd -S addr -d database -U user -P psw -Q "an sql command" -o "data.csv" -s"," -w 700
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are your headers really even over 2 lines? That sample isn't even comma delimited, so it doesn't appear to reflect the statement you've run.

Comment: Try not to use -w, meaning without setting the column_width.

Comment: Post the column definitions for the 17 columns in your export and we can confirm, but I think @WeihuiGuo is on the right track here.

Comment: @WeihuiGuo Thanks for the help it solves my problem